# Lambda to Expression

Tags: .net, linq, lambda, closures, expression

How to generate this lambda

```
() => SomeObj.SomeProp
```

using Expression.MakeMemberAccess, and this kind of methods. I know how to generate SomeObj => SomeObj.SomeProp, but problem is () part. This is somehow translated to DisplayClass.

Thanks.

This is the join that calls UvediSortiranje method. If i use inestead UvediSortiranje("Naziv") method .OrderBy(() => pfA.Naziv) all is OK!

```
Firma fA = null;
PrevodFirme pfA = null;
Jezik jA = null;

return this.Sesija.QueryOver<Firma>(() => fA)
            .UvediSortiranje(sortirajPo, fA) //!!!!
            .Left.JoinAlias(() => fA.Prevodi, () => pfA)
            .UvediSortiranje(sortirajPo, pfA) //!!!!
            .Left.JoinAlias(() => pfA.Jezik, () => jA)
            .UvediSortiranje(sortirajPo, jA) //!!!!
            .Where(Restrictions.Disjunction().Add(Restrictions.On(() => pfA.Id).IsIn(pfr)).Add(Restrictions.On(() => jA.Id).IsIn(jr)))
            .Where(() => jA.Id == jezikId)
            .Skip(odZapisa)
            .Take(brojZapisa)
            .List();
```

The other method UvediSortiranje is extension method:

```
public static class Ekst
{
   public static IQueryOver<TRoot, TSubType> UvediSortiranje<TRoot, TSubType, T>(this IQueryOver<TRoot, TSubType> ovo, string sortirajPo, T klasa) where T : class 
    {
        //provjeri da li sortiraj po zadovoljava konvenciju Objekat.Svojstvo i ako da, splituj ga na to
        var niz = sortirajPo.Split('.');
        // provjeri da li postoje ova svojstva u ovom objektu i da li se poklapaju imena

        if (niz.Length <= 0) return ovo;

        if (/*typeof(TSubType).Name == niz[0]*/ typeof(T).Name == niz[0])
        {
            //var arg = Expression.Constant(null, typeof(TSubType));
            //var body = Expression.Convert(Expression.PropertyOrField(arg, niz[1]),
            //    typeof(object));
            //var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<object>>(body);


            var param = Expression.Constant(klasa, typeof(T));
            var key = typeof(T).GetMember(niz[1]).First();
            //var rhs = Expression.MakeMemberAccess(Expression.Constant(itemToCompare), key);
            var lhs = Expression.MakeMemberAccess(param, key);
            //var body = Expression.Equal(lhs, rhs);

            var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<object>>(
            MemberExpression.MakeMemberAccess(param, key)
        );

            //lambda = (() => Expression.PropertyOrField(arg, niz[1]));

            return niz[2].ToLower() == "asc" ? ovo.OrderBy(lambda).Asc : ovo.OrderBy(lambda).Desc;
        }
        //u suprotnom vrcemo ovo bez ikakvog sortiranja
        return ovo;
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems like a pretty clear question to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally succeeded. It was the problem that NHibernate was parsing obj1.propert1.propert2 because of localy scoped lambda expression. Because of this, I had to create code to create new class at runtime and pass it to the method.

```
public static Type CreateMyNewType
 (string newTypeName, string propertyName, Type propertyType, Type baseClassType)
    {
        // create a dynamic assembly and module 
        AssemblyBuilder assemblyBldr =
        Thread.GetDomain().DefineDynamicAssembly(new AssemblyName("tmpAssembly"),
        AssemblyBuilderAccess.Run);
        ModuleBuilder moduleBldr = assemblyBldr.DefineDynamicModule("tmpModule");

        // create a new type builder
        TypeBuilder typeBldr = moduleBldr.DefineType
        (newTypeName, TypeAttributes.Public | TypeAttributes.Class, baseClassType);

        // Generate a private field for the property
        FieldBuilder fldBldr = typeBldr.DefineField
        ("_" + propertyName, propertyType, FieldAttributes.Private);
        // Generate a public property
        PropertyBuilder prptyBldr =
                    typeBldr.DefineProperty(propertyName,
            PropertyAttributes.None, propertyType, new Type[] { propertyType });
        // The property set and property get methods need the following attributes:
        MethodAttributes GetSetAttr = MethodAttributes.Public | MethodAttributes.HideBySig;
        // Define the "get" accessor method for newly created private field.
        MethodBuilder currGetPropMthdBldr =
                    typeBldr.DefineMethod("get_value", GetSetAttr, propertyType, null);

        // Intermediate Language stuff... as per Microsoft
        ILGenerator currGetIL = currGetPropMthdBldr.GetILGenerator();
        currGetIL.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
        currGetIL.Emit(OpCodes.Ldfld, fldBldr);
        currGetIL.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

        // Define the "set" accessor method for the newly created private field.
        MethodBuilder currSetPropMthdBldr = typeBldr.DefineMethod
        ("set_value", GetSetAttr, null, new Type[] { propertyType });

        // More Intermediate Language stuff...
        ILGenerator currSetIL = currSetPropMthdBldr.GetILGenerator();
        currSetIL.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
        currSetIL.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_1);
        currSetIL.Emit(OpCodes.Stfld, fldBldr);
        currSetIL.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
        // Assign the two methods created above to the PropertyBuilder's Set and Get
        prptyBldr.SetGetMethod(currGetPropMthdBldr);
        prptyBldr.SetSetMethod(currSetPropMthdBldr);
        // Generate (and deliver) my type
        return typeBldr.CreateType();
    }

   public static IQueryOver<TRoot, TSubType> UvediSortiranje<TRoot, TSubType, T>(this IQueryOver<TRoot, TSubType> ovo, string sortirajPo, T klasa, string naziv)
    {
        //provjeri da li sortiraj po zadovoljava konvenciju Objekat.Svojstvo i ako da, splituj ga na to
        var niz = sortirajPo.Split('.');
        // provjeri da li postoje ova svojstva u ovom objektu i da li se poklapaju imena

        if (niz.Length <= 0) return ovo;

        if (/*typeof(TSubType).Name == niz[0]*/ typeof(T).Name == niz[0])
        {
            //var arg = Expression.Constant(null, typeof(TSubType));
            //var body = Expression.Convert(Expression.PropertyOrField(arg, niz[1]),
            //    typeof(object));
            //var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<object>>(body);


            var tip = CreateMyNewType("brza2", naziv, typeof(T), typeof(object));

            var newClassBase = Activator.CreateInstance(tip);

            dynamic nesto = newClassBase;

            var parameter = Expression.Parameter(nesto.GetType());
            var memberExpression = Expression.Property(parameter, naziv);
            //var parameter2 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));
            var memberExpression2 = Expression.Property(memberExpression, niz[1]);
            Expression conversion = Expression.Convert(memberExpression2, typeof(object));
            var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<object>>(conversion);


            //lambda = (() => Expression.PropertyOrField(arg, niz[1]));

            return niz[2].ToLower() == "asc" ? ovo.OrderBy(lambda).Asc : ovo.OrderBy(lambda).Desc;
        }
        //u suprotnom vrcemo ovo bez ikakvog sortiranja
        return ovo;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

That's `Expression.Lambda(body)`.

Answer (score 0):

If you know how to generate `SomeObj => SomeObj.SomeProp` then you should be able to generate a lambda without parameters by calling `Expression.Lambda` specifying only the body.

So to have `Foo => body` you'd do something like:

```
var lambdaExpression = Expression.Lambda(bodyExpression, Expression.Parameter(typeof(int), "Foo"));
```

To have `() => body` you'd just do:

```
var lambdaExpression = Expression.Lambda(bodyExpression);
```

EDIT: Since the property is provided at runtime as a string (I'm guessing it's the property name):

```
LambdaExpression MakeLambda(Expression baseExpression, string fieldName) {
    var member = typeof(Foo).GetMember(fieldName).First();
    var bodyExpression = Expression.MakeMemberAccess(baseExpression, member);
    var lambdaExpression = Expression.Lambda(bodyExpression);
}
```

Comment: Sorry, just a small correction to my question. SomeProp should be provided in runtime as a string. So some variable x = "SomeProp" should be introduced to the method. I'll try your suggestions, but I'm sure it will be more complex?

Comment: @user2779330 It's basically the same, really. I added an edit to my answer, but nearly nothing changes in the code. Or did you mean "runtime" as in "each time the lambda is executed" and not "when the lambda is constructed"?

Comment: @user2779330 Not really, what am I supposed to see?

Comment: The difference is in red. This <>c__DisplayClass is generated because of the variable is in local scope to the method in the class. When I manually build expression, this part is missing. Anyway, I'm trying to pass runtime built lambda expression based on string to NHibernate OrderBy function. It uses syntax like .OrderBy(() => Class.Property), but i have Property only as a string. When I manually build lambda expression this way, it gives me errors. Thanks.

Comment: @user2779330 Are you sure NHibernate's OrderBy is used like that and not `Class => Class.Property`? What error are you getting?

Comment: you can see my classes in my updated question. The error is that "Naziv" property cannot be found on "Firma" Class. "Firma" class is first class in join, and it should not look in that one. It should use "PrevodFirme" instead (second join class).

Comment: @user2779330 Please try to simplify the code as much as possible before posting. Post only the shortest code that still has your error. Either way, you're passing `fA` in the first call, so it will look for the property there. When you pass `pfA` *then* it will search in `PrevodFirme`.

Comment: yes. just to explain shortly. input to second method are strings like "PrevodFirme.Naziv.asc". This is splitted to array, and if typeof(pfA) == "PrevodFirme" than it enter the Expression building code. So it is really pfA and not fA. The problem is that created expression does not have Type information at all, because it does not embed info of local variable pfA. This is that <>c__DisplayClass i was talking about...

Comment: @user2779330 Huh, it does seem to have type information. `Expression.Constant(klasa, typeof(T))` specifies that the Constant has type T. Expressions have a field named `Type` that indicates the type of the expression result.

Comment: here is image with expression that works (green one is .OrderBy(() => pfA.Naziv), and one that doesn't .UvediSortiranje("PrevodFirme.Naziv.asc"). You can see the difference. http://i40.tinypic.com/voppg4.png

Comment: @bojanv55 The value of the constant is `null`. Perhaps that is causing the problems?

Comment: No, i tried to instantiate it. Same problem (trough, expression three is now a bit different, but still not same as () => pfA.Naziv)

Comment: @bojanv55 Try to isolate the problem more. Develop the shortest possible snippet of code that can be compiled and still has your problem and then edit the question. http://sscce.org/